# UIMenuController strange behavior between UITableViewCell and UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uimenucontroller

In my app after long press on a cell the `UIMenuController` pop that I configured according to my need, selecting any option like `copy` also working fine but after that when I tap or long press on my `UITextView` the `UIMenuController` still pop over the cell not on my `UITextView` but perform action on `UITextView`. Why? Please see the screenshot.

[image: a]

Comment: We can't differentiate the object (whether it's table view cell or text view) which posted notification `UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification` and your code is reacting to this notification to add menu controller on cells. I am also facing same problem, let's see who can answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the target rect for the uitextfield and set the superview for the frame as given code, try this

```
UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Paste", nil]];
[menu setTargetRect:textfield.frame inView:self.view];
[menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

Might be helpful for you.